# toDataURL returns different base64 value than expected

Tags: javascript, html, png, base64

If I look at the base64 encoding of a [test.png](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/d9/Test.png) file using [this tool](http://www.greywyvern.com/code/php/binary2base64), I get a base64 string that is different than if I drew that png on an HTML canvas and did toDataURL.  Why is that? How am I supposed to draw PNGs onto a canvas then save it if toDataURL gives me incorrect results?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

How did you draw your image using your canvas context?
I think the difference is you drew the image with different size
`context.drawImage(imageObj,destX,destY);`
keep your canvas's width and height the exact size of your original image size,it'll be ok

Comment: The image I'm placing is 400x400 but in my code, I'm scaling it to 600x600 like this:
<br>

'code'
mycanvas= document.getElementById("mycanvas");
mycanvas_context = mycanvas.getContext("2d");

var image = new Image();
image.onload = function(){ mycanvas_context.drawImage(image, 0, 0, 600, 600); };
image.src='images/test.png'; 

final_image = mycanvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg");

Comment: I just tried scaling the image to 600x600. I.e. the same size as my canvas and I still get an empty image when I save it out.

Comment: I'm sorry,could you please give me an jsfiddle address